# How do you depict method / operation dependency in a class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Is there a way to depict dependency of methods of the same class in a class diagram. I have a class which has two methods :-

```
getArrayListOfLotteries()
removeDuplicateElementsOftheList(ArrayList listOfLotteries)
```

when you call `getArrayListOfLotteries` which is a public method , the private method `removeDuplicateElementsOftheList` would be called before the former returns. Is there a way to somehow show this in a class diagram ?

Answer (score 1):

In the **structural** class **diagram** you can show that `getArrayListOfLoterries` is public and that `removeDuplicateElementsOftheList` is private or protected (see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/visibility.html)

Then you can use e.g. **behavioral** sequence **diagram** to show that `getArrayListOfLoterries` calls `removeDuplicateElementsOftheList` by drawing overlapping execution or sending a message to self (see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#execution)

In my opinion it is perfectly legal to combine both aspects (both kinds of diagram) into one combined diagram. As far as I remember specification does not disallow it (***TODO: link some proof)***).

Pure class diagram does not have features to display more complex behavioral aspects (***TODO: give some examples of less complex vs. more complex aspects***)